# Can't make keyboard arrows work on react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

Currently picked up a project that has `react-datepicker` and one of the issues is that the keyboard arrows don't really do anything while they should.
This is the component

```
import React, { FC, useMemo } from 'react'
import moment, { Moment } from 'moment'
import { default as ReactDatePicker } from 'react-datepicker'

import css from './date-picker.module.css'
import ArrowIcon from '../Icons/ArrowIcon'

interface Props {
  id: string
  label: string
  icon: JSX.Element
  date: Moment | null
  onChange: Function
  minDate?: Moment | null
  maxDate?: Moment | null
  selectsStart?: boolean
  selectsEnd?: boolean
}

const months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
]

const customHeader = ({
  date,
  decreaseMonth,
  increaseMonth,
  prevMonthButtonDisabled,
  nextMonthButtonDisabled,
}: any) => (
  <div className={css.header}>
    <button
      className={css.backArrow}
      onClick={decreaseMonth}
      disabled={prevMonthButtonDisabled}
    >
      <ArrowIcon width={16} height={16} className={css.arrowIcon} />
    </button>
    <span>
      {months[date.getMonth()]} {date.getFullYear()}
    </span>
    <button
      className={css.nextArrow}
      onClick={increaseMonth}
      disabled={nextMonthButtonDisabled}
    >
      <ArrowIcon width={16} height={16} className={css.arrowIcon} />
    </button>
  </div>
)

const DatePicker: FC<Props> = ({
  label,
  icon,
  date,
  onChange,
  minDate,
  maxDate,
  selectsStart,
  selectsEnd,
}) => {
  const dateObj = useMemo(() => (date ? date.toDate() : null), [date])
  const minDateObj = useMemo(() => (minDate ? minDate.toDate() : null), [
    minDate,
  ])
  const maxDateObj = useMemo(() => (maxDate ? maxDate.toDate() : null), [
    maxDate,
  ])

  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <div className={css.label}>{label}</div>
      <div className={`${css.wrapper}`}>
        {icon}
        <ReactDatePicker
          selected={dateObj}
          className={css.input}
          calendarClassName={css.calendar}
          showTimeSelect
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
          onChange={newDate => {
            if (newDate) {
              onChange(moment(newDate))
            }
          }}
          startDate={minDateObj}
          endDate={maxDateObj}
          minDate={minDateObj}
          maxDate={maxDateObj}
          selectsStart={selectsStart}
          selectsEnd={selectsEnd}
          showPopperArrow={false}
          popperModifiers={{
            offset: {
              enabled: true,
              offset: '-28px, 4px',
            },
          }}
          renderCustomHeader={customHeader}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DatePicker
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1338

Comment: @Konowy, I did, thank you. I ended up finding the issue.

The problem were this two props: `minDate={minDateObj}` & `maxDate={maxDateObj}`

Answer (score 1):

Removing `minDate={minDateObj}` & `maxDate={maxDateObj}` solved my issue although I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

you did not need to remove mindate and maxDate, instead minDateObj and maxDateObj should have been initialised to undefined instead of null if they are not being used. Setting to undefined means the minDate and maxDate attributes will not to be included and hence the user can choose any date using the keyboard buttons.